# Instant.now() passed in spark forEachBatch function not getting updated

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

```
output
.writeStream()
*.foreachBatch(new function(name, Instant.now()))*
.outputMode("append")
.option("checkpointLocation", "/path/")
.start();
```

Instant.now() passed in foreachBatch doesnt get updated for every micro batch processing, instead it just takes the time from when the spark job was first deployed. What I am I missing here?